# Declaring a Map of String to Class, for classes of a specific type

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections, jar

I'm trying to do a command line wrapper class around some other other classes that all have a main method.

I've declared a map of Strings to classes, but now I'd like to insure that all the classes implement a particular interface.

The idea is that you'd give the a class alias or "command name" as the first argument, then I'd call the main of that class and pass the rest of the argv array to it.

Initially I had this:

```
static final Map<String, Class> CLASSES = new LinkedHashMap<String,Class>() {{
    put( "command1", com.foobar.package_a.ClassOne.class   );
    put( "command2", com.foobar.package_a.ClassTwo.class   );
    put( "command3", com.foobar.package_b.ClassThree.class );
    ...
}};
```

But I wanted to let users run the command with no args and list the classes and what they do.  And from previous work, most of the classes did have a description.

I decided to formalize this in an interface:

```
public interface HasDescription {
    String getDescription();
}
```

And then:

```
public class ClassOne implements HasDescription {
    // I'd prefer static, but that's a different concern
    public String getDescription() {
        return "check files for gophers";
    }
    ... rest of class ...
}
```

But I'm not sure how to declare it, I've had many variations.  Here's one example of what **doesn't** work:

```
static final Map<String, Class<T implements HasDescription>> CLASSES = new LinkedHashMap<String,Class<T implements HasDescription>>() {{
    put( "command1", com.foobar.package_a.ClassOne.class   );
    put( "command2", com.foobar.package_a.ClassTwo.class   );
    put( "command3", com.foobar.package_b.ClassThree.class );
}};
```

Variations / Lessons:

- I've tried with an without a leading letter inside the angle brackets
- I've tried both `implements` and `extends`
- Even in Java 7 you can't just put `new LinkedHashMap<>()` when declaring it inline

Questions:

- Ideally .getDescription() would be static.
- I assume that if I had the correct signature, then pulling it out of the hash with .get() I'd assign to a similarly declared variable (sans the top level Mop< >)
- If a pull out a properly qualified class variable, is there a shortcut or special version of reflection that just lets me say something like ( (HasDescription)clazz ).getDescription() ?
- Wondering if I'm either reinventing the wheel, or that there's some reason this is a horribly bad idea
- Does specifying that all classes must implement a particular interface buy me anything in this usage scenario?  At a minimum, seems like it lets the compiler do some checking for me.  At runtime, I'm wondering if getting a qualified class reference gives me an special advantage over regular reflection.

Why an I doing this?

- I'm having Maven produce a full, self contained .jar file
- I'd like folks to run it with just java -jar my_jar.jar ... so I need to choose one specific class; you'd run with `java -jar projname.jar command_name arg1 arg2 arg3`
- If you run with just `java -jar projname.jar` you get a list of classes and what they do
- The alternative is to run each command as `java -cp projname.jar com.foobar.package_a.ClassOne arg1 arg2 arg3` but this is a bit ugly for folks to type in, and would require .sh and .bat for each class name.

Comment: Have you considered using an enum instead of a map?

Comment: May be I'm not getting the purpose of your question correctly, but why do you want to invoke the `main()` method yourself? Also, a Jar file can only have a single `Main` class. Are you trying to have multiple `main` class? I don't see how that is possible, unless you provide the class name explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't use type parameters like that. The type parameters can either be declared at *Class level* or *method level*. With field declaration like that, you have to use wildcards:

```
static final Map<String, Class<? extends HasDescription>> CLASSES = new LinkedHashMap<String,Class<? extends HasDescription>>() {{
    put( "command1", com.foobar.package_a.ClassOne.class   );
    put( "command2", com.foobar.package_a.ClassTwo.class   );
    put( "command3", com.foobar.package_b.ClassThree.class );
}};
```

> I've tried both `implements` and `extends`

In generics, you just use `extends` keyword to represent both the concepts.

> Ideally .getDescription() would be static.

No you can't do that. That would not give you polymorphic behaviour that you want currently.

> If a pull out a properly qualified class variable, is there a shortcut or special version of reflection that just lets me say something like `( (HasDescription)clazz ).getDescription()` ?

If you want to invoke the method like that, then why are you storing the `Class` instance instead of the instance itself? If you are storing the `Class` instance, you would have to instantiate it using [`Class#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method, and ensure that all the implementating classes provide a 0-arg constructor for that.

> Does specifying that all classes must implement a particular interface buy me anything in this usage scenario?

If you're storing the `Class` instance, then you have to do that. But if you store the instances themselves, then just keeping the reference as `HasDescription` would work fine:

```
static final Map<String, HasDescription> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("command1", new com.foobar.package_a.ClassOne());
map.put("command2", new com.foobar.package_a.ClassTwo());
```

and then you can do:

```
map.get("command1").getDescription();
```

Comment: Rohit, thanks... I'm not wild about instantiating each of the classes just to get their description, that's why I thought static methods would be better, but as you say it's not possible.  As currently implemented, I don't have uniform visible zero arg constructors because the classes take args and I do some non-trivial setup in the constructors.  Any advice on that?

Comment: @MarkBennett Then you've to get appropriate constructor for every class using `Class#getConstructor()` method, giving the `Class` instance for the parameter types the constructor takes as argument of this method, and then use `Constructor#newInstance()` method passing actual arguments to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 1):

You would not declare the Interface in your string to class map. You can see if a particular class implements an interface by using something like:

```
Class<?> testClass = [ lookup your class, or test class before adding to  your map];
boolean isProperInterface = HasDescription.class.isAssignableFrom(testClass);
```

(Under different circumstances you might check to see if an object is an instance of a class or interface by using

```
 boolean isGood = object instanceof [class or interface name]
```